# React Redux: how to prevent state from getting reset when props/state change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

In my React Native app, I have the following constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  this.state = {flag: false}
}
```

and a `<TouchableOpacity>` that triggers a callback like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => {
    this.props.function1();
    this.setState({flag: true})
  }}
/>
```

`function1()` changes a prop that I'm getting from Redux:

```
function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {
    var1: state.var1
  }
}
```

The problem is that whenever `function1()` fires, my constructor gets called again, so `flag` gets reset to `false`. I need it to stay as `true`. What can I do here?

**EDIT:** I have the following Modal that gets switched on and off with `flag`:

```
<Modal
  visible={this.state.flag}
/>
```

Comment: `The problem is that whenever function1() fires, my constructor gets called again` That's unusual. We'll need to see more code to figure out exactly why the component is unmounting and remounting. A couple guesses are that you might be changing a `key`, or you might be creating new types of components in the middle of rendering.

Comment: @NicholasTower What does it mean to change a key, or to create a new type of component? `flag` does set a modal to be visible if that helps.

Comment: `What does it mean to change a key`. Like, if you're rendering `<MyComponent key={foo} />` and foo changes. `or to create a new type of component` Eg, you might have code like  `class SomeComponent extends React.Component` in the middle of rendering.

Comment: @NicholasTower I added an edit to the end of my original post that shows how the `visible` key changes when `flag` changes.

Comment: We'll need to see a lot more code to figure out why this component is unmounting and remounting. Components don't unmount themselves, it's up to the parent component to do that. So for this component with the constructor (i don't even know it's name), go to its *parent* component, and see how that decides to render this component. If it always renders this component, then go to *its* parent and check there. Somewhere, there will be conditional rendering, or a key that's changing, or a component type that's being redefined on every render.

Comment: Ok, let me look into this and get back to you. All understood ^

Comment: for just quick fix, you can store your modal key in the redux itself